# Parse-Server error on initialization: "Tried to ensure field uniqueness for a class that already has duplicates."

Tags: mongodb, parse-server

Edit: Solved below. A note for the repo maintainers that I know browse here: I notice that many of the offending users are very old. They are from when we forked the database ages ago. I'm not sure what changed, but something did, without requiring an npm update, that caused this error to start appearing. These users have been duplicate within our database for years, yet we just started getting this exception yesterday. Not sure if that's an "issue" worth looking into, or if it's the result of an issue being resolved.

I found some similar questions but they are due to authentication errors, which I'm not experiencing.

I hit the above error message for both email and username, which isn't surprising because I use the user's e-mail as their username. What is surprising is that this error message starting occurring mid-day yesterday after no changes I could pin to be the source of the issue. There were no new users created that had a duplicate e-mail / username, and I was unable to change a username or e-mail through parse-dashboard or the API to be a duplicate.

More oddly, this is occurring on both production and test servers, both having started at the same time. One was a duplicate of the other at one point, but the fork was three years ago.

Any ideas where I can start to try to solve this? It doesn't seem to stop the server from functioning but I'm getting an uncaught exception breakpoint triggering every time I start my debug server.

I was looking into mongo's aggregate kinda of using this guide as a basis:
https://www.compose.com/articles/finding-duplicate-documents-in-mongodb/

However, nothing comes up when I try `db.User.aggregate([{$group: { _id: {username: "$email"}, uniqueIds: {$addToSet: "$_id"}, count: {$sum: 1}}}, {$match: { count: {"$gt": 1}}}]);`, and if I do _User (the actual name of the collection) I get the error `E QUERY    TypeError: Cannot call method 'aggregate' of undefined`

For clearer formatting:

`db._User.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group:{ 
        _id: {
          username: "$email"
        }, uniqueIds: {
          $addToSet: "$_id"
        }, count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }, {
      $match: {
        count: {
          "$gt": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);`

Anybody have tips on how I can figure out where these duplicates are or why I'm just now getting this error?

Comment: Realized `list` is the name of their collection, updated my attempt

Comment: If you really intend to raise an issue for the repos maintainers, you should open it on Github.

Comment: @flovilmart I was going to but figured it would have been a bit of a misuse, as I thought it was an issue with *my* setup and not the repo itself. Although, I still have no idea why old users would just now have started giving us this warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mongo shell doesn't like all collection names, so they're not dot accessible.  I just had to use .getCollection() instead of .collection, and it worked perfectly!

`db.getCollection("_User").aggregate(
  [
    {
      $group:{ 
        _id: {
          username: "$email"
        }, uniqueIds: {
          $addToSet: "$_id"
        }, count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }, {
      $match: {
        count: {
          "$gt": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ]
);`